# Sidebar transition with React and Redux?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, transition

So I have a SideDrawer that I'm rendering like this in the root App component:

```js
  render() {
    const { isOpen } = this.props;
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <SideDrawer />
        {/* isOpen && <SideDrawer /> */}
        <Routes ..../>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}
```

This is the reducer:

```js
export const drawer = (state = initialState, { type, payload }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case CLOSE_DRAWER:
      return { ...state, isOpen: false };
    case OPEN_DRAWER:
      return { isOpen: true, movieId: payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And In the `SideDrawer` component, I was using the state of the drawer and css to handle the transition:

```js
export const SideDrawer = ({ isOpen, closeDrawer, movieId }) => {
  const drawerClass = cx({
    container: true,
    open: isOpen,
  });
  return (
    <div className={drawerClass}>
      <button className={styles.button} onClick={closeDrawer}>
        <img src={backButton} alt={text.alt} />
      </button>
      <MovieBanner movieId={movieId} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Now, my mentor wants me to render the SideDrawer conditionally. If `isOpen` is true, then render the SideDrawer. However,  the problem is that the transition is not going to work, because I'd only be rendering the `SideDrawer` when the state of `isOpen` is true. The only way it's working now is if I just render it all the time on the `App` component so I can keep track of the state and add my CSS transition when the state changes from `false` to `true`

My mentor mentioned to only render the SideDrawer if the SideDrawer is open, but I need to have it rendered to know the previous state of it no?

Comment: Why do you need to manage the SideDrawer through a reducer-state? Use component-state, use a button to toggle between isOpen state. Have it mounted at all times. If isOpen is true, display sideBar, if not, display button.

Comment: I put it in a reducer since I will be calling the SideDrawer from within different components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When an element is removed from the DOM, it will no longer be shown to the user. This also means `transition`s on it will have no impact.

If you would like to use transitions, keep the element in the DOM at least until the transitions have finished, or always. Here is a demo of two `<div>`s, first one is always in the DOM, the second one only when `sidebarOn` is `true`:

```js
function Demo() {
  const [sidebarOn, setSidebarOn] = React.useState(false)
  const toggleSidebar = () => setSidebarOn(!sidebarOn)
  
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={toggleSidebar}>toggle</button>
      <div className={'sidebar ' + sidebarOn}>always rendered</div>
      {sidebarOn && 
        <div className={'sidebar ' + sidebarOn}>only rendered when on</div>
      }
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<Demo />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```css
.sidebar {
  background-color: yellow;
  opacity: 0;
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 500ms;
}
.sidebar.true {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.6/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.6/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

---

There exists a [`transitionend` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/transitionend_event), which you ***could*** use to remove the element once the transition is over, but support in browsers is not widespread enough at this time.

Comment: Interesting, this seems doable. It's hard to wrap my head around how to re-write this component with the redux state but I understand what the goal is here. Would the same concept apply to closing the side drawer?

Comment: I think your reducer is probably fine. Just always render the `<SideDrawer>` (as the code you posted already does). Basically just a confirmation that you're correct and your mentor's advice was wrong

Comment: Ok good to know hehe, so this is something I can bring up to him and let him know that it's not the end of the world if the component is constantly rendered on the page.